# Is it a blessing to live long on the earth?

Tags: nature-of-god

> [Ephesians 6:2-3] "Honour thy father and mother; (which is the first commandment with promise;) That it may be well with thee, and thou mayest live long on the earth."

Are we supposed to desire to live long on the earth?  It seems to me that after someone in born again he/she is looking forward to meeting and serving and worshiping our Lord forever.

All these can be done although with difficulties on this earth. I am not saying we should desire to not live and serve our Lord on this earth.

It is also not about us but about Him.
So is God more pleased in giving us more years, maybe because we get the chance to become more pure?

Comment: By honoring our parents (and they theirs etc) we add their lives to ours. So we live long. It is an instant reward and always true and kept by God. Methuselah honored his parents and they theirs for many generations - he did not live that long himself!

Answer (score 3):

> [**Philippians 1:21-24** (NASB)](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/philippians/1.html)
>   For to me, to live is Christ and to die is gain. But if I am to live on in the flesh, this will mean fruitful labor for me; and I do not know which to choose. But I am hard-pressed from both directions, having the desire to depart and be with Christ, for that is very much better;  yet to remain on in the flesh is more necessary for your sake.

Paul's desire was to go home to be with the Lord. He was, however, content to stay for the sake of serving others. Being blessed with a long life gives us more of an opportunity to glorify God, which is good for us, too.

**Addendum**: It is also possible for our desire to leave the troubles of this life behind to have selfish motivations. It is better (for us) to be with the Lord, but it is better for others that we remain here. What should an unselfish person choose?

Answer (score 3):

"Is it a blessing to live long on the earth?"

The book of Job answers this question to a large degree. He certainly didn't feel blessed when he was in torment from Satan. Many can relate to this:

> [Job 3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=job%203&version=GNT) - Job wants to die, wishes he was never born.

But the "Second part" of Job's life was blessed, and fruitful. He was able to enjoy many aspects of a good life **on earth**:

> [Job 42:12-16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2042:12-16&version=GNT) - Job's second part of his life blessed more than formerly.

Addressing your question in more depth: King Hezekiah was especially fond of worshipping in truth and purity. After all of his good works, he found he was going to die. But God *blessed* him with longer years:

> [2 Kings 20:4-6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2020:4-6&version=NKJV) - Hezekiah's years extended.

Psalms states the righteous will live *forever* upon the earth:

> [Psalm 37:29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2037:29&version=GNT) - Righteous possess the earth.

As you probably know, Adam and Eve, as well as their immediate descendants lived a very long time (almost 1000 years), and gradually the human life span declined to 80 years/average.

Without naming too many verses, Christ himself as well as his followers raised people back to *life on earth*.

Back to the Example of Job, ***and the second part of his life*** - the bible implies by examples and statements that humans can expect to live a long time on earth, **resurrected**, enjoying beauty and prosperity they did not have formerly, in an emotionally, physically, and spiritually healed state. Its a comforting thought for those who have been struck with poverty, disease, and various troubles which cripple advantages in this present world.

The book of Job applies to the human race in general - especially those pleasing to their creator.

**To answer your question: ** Just as we wish to serve our creator, seeking his interest -- he is always taking the lead in seeking our interests, such as those he put into our hearts:

> [Ecclesiastes 3:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%203:11&version=AMP) - Put eternity into the hearts of man.
>
> [Revelation 21:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021:3&version=AMP) - Tent of God with Mankind.

It is indeed a great blessing to live a long time on the earth, and its one that has been put into our hearts and instincts. Its the renewed earth, not under the power of the wicked, which we will unquestionably feel blessed to live in.

Answer (score 2):

The Gospel Age is still going. Think of friends and family who haven't accepted Jesus, evaluate your own salvation. Have you been reading the word daily? I feel like the Lord has a lot of work left for me to do. Paul could have wrapped things earlier, but he ended up going for the goal by staying on Earth as long as possible.

Comment: I think this hits the nail on the head. Long life is a blessing in which to serve the Lord and see others won to Him.